# Python Streaming Dataflow "WriteToPubSub" behaviour

Tags: python-3.x, streaming, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying out a Streaming dataflow to read from PubSub and write to another PubSub. I am using python 3.7.3 version. The pipeline looks something like this,

```
lines = (pipe | "Read from PubSub" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=TOPIC).with_output_types(bytes)
    | "Transformation" >> beam.ParDo(PubSubToDict())
    | "Write to PubSub" >> beam.io.WriteToPubSub(topic=OUTPUT, with_attributes=False)
    )
```

The "Transformation" step is something where I need to so some custom transformation. I am ensuring that the output of this transform is bytes. Something like this,

```
class PubSubToDict(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        """pubsub input is a byte string"""
        data = element.decode('utf-8')
        """do some custom transform here"""
        data = data.encode('utf-8')
        return data
```

Now when I publish a test message, I get an error like this,

```
ERROR: Data being published to Pub/Sub must be sent as a bytestring. [while running 'Write to PubSub']
```

I managed to solve this by returning an array instead like this,

```
return [data]
```

But I don't know the reason why this worked. So I was looking for an explanation to this.

Regards,
Prasad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked because ParDo lets a pipeline step return multiple output elements for a single input element, so it expects an iterable to be returned.

you could also do `yield data`

Comment: Ok. Because in some other batch Dataflows I am returning a dict object from ParDo functions but not wrapping it as an array [] and there it seems to work.

Comment: was that in a `beam.ParDo()` or in a `beam.Map()`? `apache_beam` provides the helpers `beam.FlatMap()` and `beam.Map()` to minimize the amount of pipeline code you have to write and `beam.Map()` has a 1-1 input element to output element ratio

Comment: Hi Alex, I noticed the other code that we have. In that I see that when a ParDo() has to pass the output to another ParDo() there we have not returned an array. However, when the ParDo() has to pass the output to inbuilt transform like WriteToBigQuery() or WriteToFirestore() there we have used an array. So may be these inbuilt transforms need an iterable object as you mentioned.